# Docker friendlyhello from tutorial does not run on mac

Tags: python, macos, docker

I am going through the tutorials here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app and have arrived at the point where i am supposed to run this command:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

and nothing is happening.  If i go to http://localhost:4000/ all i get is the "This site can't be reached" error message.

Here is the output of some commands I've tried to debug this

```
docker --version
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
02424cf44e10        friendlyhello       "python2"           2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                        tender_beaver
da7b5b031aeb        friendlyhello       "python2"           10 minutes ago      Exited (0) 10 minutes ago                       competent_mclean
02ea969400c5        friendlyhello       "python2"           14 minutes ago      Exited (0) 14 minutes ago                       focused_noether
caa8786614f1        hello-world         "/hello"            26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                       laughing_mendeleev
```

I am running this on a Mac with macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6
If there is any other version or environment information that you think might be helpful to debug this just ask and I will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well crud, I have fixed the problem but still don't know what caused it in the first place.

This is what I did.  First, because I have all sorts of other crap on my machine including other virtual machines and apache and stuff I decided to just reboot the machine.  On reboot it still was not working so I started messing around with the IP address listed on the last line of the app.py file

here is the app.py file for reference:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I tried all sorts of things instead of 0.0.0.0 including

```
localhost
127.0.0.1
1.2.3.4
```

I then thought, hmmm maybe i need to add a listing in the /etc/hosts file so i added this:

```
192.168.33.33   test.docker
```

then cleared my dns cache and set the IP in the app.py file to: 192.168.33.33  Still not working.

So in desperation I reset it back to 0.0.0.0 and tried one last time and for some dang reason now it's working.  No idea why, and I would like to know exactly what i did to fix it still (if anyone has any insight)